# Later code affecting earlier code, debugger going in to code block it shouldn't be entering

Tags: c#, control-flow

I have the following code ...

```
var len = request.Code.Trim().Length;
if (len.Equals(0))
{
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("request.Code");
}

try
{
    var obj = _repository.GetSomething(request.Code);
    return Result.Success(obj);
}
catch (Exception)
{
    return Result.Failure(MessageCode.MissingData);
}
```

I am running through this code with the debugger (via a unit test) and it is going in to the `if (len.Equals(0))` block when len is 3. I've also tried changing the if statements to `if (string.IsNullOrWhitespace(request.Code))` and I get the same problem.

If I remove the try/catch and leave just the code within the try block, everything is fine.

So, can anyone explain what on earth is going on here?

**EDIT:**
To clarify the value of request.Code is "WH1", therefore len is 3. Which is what the debugger tells me just before I try to step over the if statement.

**EDIT 2:**
I was getting a failing test which is what led me to debug this code. But now the test is passing, I changed another piece of code not shown in my question. All my tests pass now but when I debug through it the debugger still looks as if it's executing the throw within the first if block. Very confusing, but if I step over the statement it carries on as I would have expected.

It appears to be a bug of some kind in the debugger as the code isn't being executed, merely the cursor is going to that code and doing nothing with it.

Comment: what is your issue? what is the value of request.Code and what is your expected result of the check: if (string.IsNullOrWhitespace(request.Code)) ?

Comment: @DavidePiras I have added a little clarification to my question.

Comment: you don't have a hidden ; after the if statement - maybe off to the right of the screen?

Comment: @Jimmy - good idea, but no. As I said if I remove the try/catch the problem goes away. I just made sure in my editor and removed everything between the closing bracket and the opening brace.

Comment: Just checking: you're sure you've recompiled the code after making changes, right?

Comment: Strange things can happen in Debug vs. Release modes. I'm not sure if this applies in managed code situations like C#, but you can see weird behaviour in C/C++ if you're accidentally running with optimizations on? Perhaps try to make sure that's all turned off? Or maybe something insidious about not running the code you're actually building...

Comment: Have you compiled it in debug mode? If you use release mode the compiler may rearrange the code, so debugging may show the wrong line being executed.

Comment: It's debug mode, and the line it's executing isn't replicated anywhere that I can see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code wasn't being run at all, the debugger was just going to that line but not actually executing the code.

Comment: How did you come about determining that this was your problem?

Comment: when i looked at my watches i could seethat the code wasn't actually being executed

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this before if the code doesn't match the code being debugged. Are you debugging the process using "Attach to Process" or are you just going up to the Debug menu and choosing "Start Debugging" (F5)? Is the code you show above part of the project you're debugging or is it in a related assembly?

You could also try doing a Rebuild of the whole solution.